# set a field in a mongo document with another field value bring the $ instead

Tags: mongodb

When I do this query:

```
db.getCollection("myCollection").updateMany(
    {},
    { "$set" : { "updateDate" : '$creationDate'}}
    )
```

I endup with the value "$creationDate" instead of , well, the date of creation .

Any idea why?

I use mongo 4.4.25

Comment: you can use aggregation pipeline in updates now  
using ([]) https://mongoplayground.net/p/baXTkHU4Hb_  or https://mongoplayground.net/p/GFhA6dVSFQm

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
db.getCollection("myCollection").updateMany(
   {},
   [ { "$set" : { "updateDate" : '$creationDate'}} ]
)
```

The second operator can be a [Update Operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.3/reference/operator/update/#std-label-update-operators) or an [Aggregation Pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.3/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#std-label-updateMany-behavior-aggregation-pipeline)